# Multiple GET-variables in yii path url

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, yii

I have a problem with my Yii urlManager. I'm using the path format and want to pass multiple get variables. The url looks like that:

```
/Yii/app/de/user/admin/id/5/test/hello
```

my .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteBase /Yii/app/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
```

I tried with the urlManager, but it doesn't work with following rules:

```
'rules' => array(
    '<language:\w+>/<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
    '<language:\w+>/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
    '<language:\w+>/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
)
```

The $_GET should look like this:

```
array(3) { 
    ["/de/user/admin"]=> string(0) ""
    ["id"]=> string(1) "5" 
    ["test"]=> string(5) "hello" 
    ["language"]=> string(2) "de" 
}
```

Can someone help me?

**EDIT:**

It musst work for a variable nummber of get parameters.

Comment: what were you expecting? app=de user=admin id=5 test=hello ?

Comment: as i said by: "The $_GEt should look like this: ..."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep the official guide [URL Management - Using named parameters](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url#using-named-parameters) as reference.

You should write a custom rule such as:

```
'<language:\w+>/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>/test/<test:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>'
```

In particular, if you want to have a variable number of arguments, you should append `/*` to the rule, something like this:

```
'<language:\w+>/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>/*'=>'<controller>/<action>',
```

With such rule, you can obtain the URL as

```
/de/user/admin/id/2/test2/hello/anotherparam/45/yap/thisothertoo
```

and bind $_GET params as

```
'id' => 2
'test2' => 'hello'
'anotherparam' => 45
'yap' => 'thisothertoo'
```

Last thing to keep in mind: check ***always*** rule precedence.

Comment: I hoped it would work for Yii 2 as well, as it would make sense, but I though Yii 2 supports this multi parameters behavior by default by setting urlFormat='path' , this is how it was accomplished in Yii 2 overcome by a workaround - https://stackoverflow.com/a/38117859/3419535

Answer (score 2):

You should simply try to add this url rule :

```
'<language:\w+>/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>/test/<test:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
```

And with Yii you don't really need to use `$_GET`, you should use action parameter binding feature : http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.controller#action-parameter-binding

Comment: But what is if my second parameter is test2? then he is named test and not test2. The problem is, that CGridView and other yii Components make links like that.

Comment: I don't think it is the same problem, you should post another question about it with more details

Comment: I think this was replied even sooner than the chosen answer, even though less verbose, I think the @soju 's answer can be replied for example in here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38115978/yii2-pretty-url-automatically-convert-everything-with-slashes-including-all-pa or with a default feature of Yii 1 , urlManager config field urlFormat='Path'

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution , you can uri component use like this ; Yii::app()->uri->segment(2);

for details follow url

http://www.hasandemir.com/how-to-get-contoller-action-segments-like-codeigniter/

Comment: your link is dead